# Can I use SFINAE to compare enum class Value?

Tags: c++

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b8e8a7836516c04)**

```
struct Banana : public FruitBase
{
    Banana(Fruit fruit, int price, std::string name, int length):
...
};

struct Apple : public FruitBase
{
    Apple(Fruit fruit, int price, std::string name):
...
};

template<typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<FruitBase> makeFruits(Fruit fruit, Ts&&... params)
{
    switch(fruit)
    {
    case Fruit::APPLE:
        return std::make_unique<Apple>(Fruit::APPLE, std::forward<Ts>(params)...);    
        break;
    case Fruit::BANANA:
        return std::make_unique<Banana>(Fruit::BANANA, std::forward<Ts>(params)...);    
        break;    
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    auto apple_ptr = makeFruits(Fruit::APPLE, 10, "gala");
    print_fruit(apple_ptr.get());
    
    auto banana_ptr = makeFruits(Fruit::BANANA, 20, "plantains", 123);
    print_fruit(banana_ptr.get());

}
```

```
main.cpp:37:5: note: candidate: 'Apple::Apple(Fruit, int, std::string)'
   37 |     Apple(Fruit fruit, int price, std::string name):
      |     ^~~~~
main.cpp:37:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided

main.cpp:26:5: note: candidate: 'Banana::Banana(Fruit, int, std::string, int)'
   26 |     Banana(Fruit fruit, int price, std::string name, int length):
      |     ^~~~~~
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided
```

**Question**> The issue is that the compiler has problems choosing which constructor for `Apple` and which one for `Banana`. I assume I could use SFINAE(i.e. with help of `std::enable_if`) to help compiler deduce the correct function. However, I didn't find an example where the checking is for VALUE instead of TYPE. Can someone give me a little hint here?

Comment: Even if not taken, all branches should be valid.

Comment: Can `Fruit fruit` be a NTTP (non-type template parameter) instead of regular function argument. (So known at compile time).

Comment: Do you mean to pass `Fruit fruit` as a template parameter instead of a parameter for the constructor? I am fine as long as it works.

Comment: BTW, strange that `Apple` takes `Fruit` as parameter... It could directly passes `Fruit::APPLE` to its base class. Currently, you can create `Apple(Fruit::BANANA, 10, "gala")`... :/

Comment: Agree. I just give some demos here and they can be improved based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if not taken, all branches should be valid

If argument is passed as template parameter (so known at compile time), you might do

```
template<Fruit fruit, typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<FruitBase> makeFruits(Ts&&... params)
{
    if constexpr (fruit == Fruit::APPLE)
        return std::make_unique<Apple>(Fruit::APPLE, std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
    else if constexpr (fruit == Fruit::BANANA)
        return std::make_unique<Banana>(Fruit::BANANA, std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
    else
        return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    auto apple_ptr = makeFruits<Fruit::APPLE>(10, "gala");
    auto banana_ptr = makeFruits<Fruit::BANANA>(20, "plantains", 123);
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35b58b47d9c8821c)

You can still add SFINAE on top of that.

Comment: So `constexpr (fruit == Fruit::APPLE)` helps the compiler to choose the correct constructor? Given a `Fruit::BANANA`, compiler will not consider `Apple` because of this line?

Comment: Another question is what if the value of `Fruit` is unknown at the compiler time. I tried to work on this factory class where the input is given through a config file or command-line option, so the `Fruit` type will be unknown in that case.

Comment: `if constexpr` allows to "discard" not taken branch. but requires condition known at compile time.

Comment: If argument is runtime, then your interface has issue anyway: `makeFruits(FruitFromCommandLine(), 10, "gala")` would be wrong for `BANANA`...